# Convert SQL Query to ORM Query

Tags: mysql, django, orm

[I have the following models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIqmi.png)

models

```
class User(models.Model):
    ur_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ur_mailid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class User_info(models.Model):
    ui_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    # ui_iduser  = models.IntegerField()
    ui_iduser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ui_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    ui_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    ...

class User_group(models.Model):
    ug_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ug_groupname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class User_groupmember(models.Model):
    # ug_groupid = models.IntegerField()
    # ug_userid = models.IntegerField()
    ug_groupid = models.ForeignKey(User_group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ug_userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Here is SQL Query:

```
select 
      a.ur_id ur_id,
      c.ug_id ug_id,
      d.ui_mailid ui_mailid,
      d.ui_firstname ui_firstname,
      d.ui_lastname ui_lastname
    from user a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        user_groupmember b ON a.ur_id = b.ug_userid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        user_group c ON c.ug_id = b.ug_userid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        user_info d ON d.ui_id = a.ur_id
    where a.ur_mailid = 'test@test.com'
```

I need to convert it in ORM Query.

Is there any way to achieve it without using raw SQL?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you please share the Model class

Comment: Can you refer to the image link?

Comment: It would be great if you could post your actual models :)

Comment: I posted the actual model.

Comment: Is there a reason you use `IntegerField` instead of `ForeignKey` for relations between models?

Comment: There is no reason. I don't know.......The actual mysql DB has an FK.

Comment: This is just basic Django relations, and easy enough to learn with good [examples on the Django site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/). A point to note, as per @kostans3k is that your models really do need to explictily inform Django which fields define the relations, using ForeignKey, OneToOneField or ManyToManyField. Hard to expect the ORM to offer any working grammar for you if you don't tell it how the models are related.

Comment: Modified model ForeignKey.........